# How to get a result for this subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `A_Lab_Project` (
        `subject_code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
        `semester` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `branch_code` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `component` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        `course_outcome` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `max_marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `syear` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
        `eyear` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

 CREATE TABLE `A_Lab_Program` (
    `subject_code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    `semester` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `branch_code` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `Question_no` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Marks_co1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Marks_co2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Marks_co3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Marks_co4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `syear` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `eyear` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL )
```

I need

```
100*(v1+v2)/v3+v4 ; 
v1 = select sum(course_outcome) from A_Lab_Project where subject_code='12csa34',
v2 = select sum(max_co) from A_Lab_Program where subject_code='12csa34', 
v3 = select max_marks from A_Lab_Project where subject_code='12csa34'
```

in a subquery please help me to write a sub query for this.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I removed the oracle tag because `ENGINE=InnoDB` is MySQL syntax

Comment: What's v4? Why do you need that as a `subquery` instead of a separate result? Based on `v1` and `v2`, `v3` could return multiple rows.

Comment: give an example of data it's better

Comment: I'm using Mysql  I have written query select a.subject_code,(100*(a+b)/(a+c) AS 'result' from (select sum(course_outcome) from A_Lab_Project where subject_code='12CS34') a,(select sum(Marks_co1) from A_Lab_Program where subject_code='12CS34') b,(select max_marks from A_Lab_Project where subject_code='12CS34') c; I'm getting an error call right parenthesis is missing

Comment: I'm using Mysql. I wrote a query select a.subject_code,(100*(a+b)/(a+c) AS 'result' from (select sum(course_outcome) from A_Lab_Project where subject_code='12CS34') a,(select sum(Marks_co1) from A_Lab_Program where subject_code='12CS34') b,(select max_marks from A_Lab_Project where subject_code='12CS34') c; which I'm getting error.  right parenthesis is missing..